# Does const rvalue references allow extra optimisations for compiler?

Tags: c++, optimization, constants, compiler-optimization, rvalue-reference

`const` modifier for function parameter in C++ means that this function can't change parameter value, but doesn't guarantee that it can't be changed by someone else during function execution. So, compiler can't do any optimizations relying on data immutability.

As I understand rvalue reference means that given object is temporary, so **nobody else have access to its data**. Can compiler make aggresive optimizations in this case?

It would allow to have faster code through some kind of

```
template<class T>
class Immutable 
{ 
private: 
    const T val; 
public: 
    operator const T && () { return std::move(val); } 
};
```

(just sample code), or passing values by `const&&` when we sure they can't be changed during function call. Is it possible, or there are some unmentioned problems?

Comment: define "changed by someone else"

Comment: It means changed by non-const reference in some other object.

Comment: see my answer. There are different scenarios for this. One is "changed by another thread", the other is "changed by same thread"

Comment: Your example proves that `const T&&` doesn't have to be bound to a temporary, and there could be several rvalue references bound to the same thing: `Immutable<int> i{}; const int&& r1 = i; const int&& r2 = i;`. So This is no different to the `const&` case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl'dr**: It doesn't enable any optimization as it doesn't guarantee in any way the object is not modified. It only adds confusion. **Don't use it!**

---

First we need to clarify what "changed by someone else" means.

- by another thread. In this case your question is not aplicabile. You need to protect your data with a `mutex` or other mechanism. Otherwise the compiler can assume that no other thread modifies the data.
- same thread, in a code not called (directly or indirectly) by the function. Not possible.
- same thread, in a code called (directly or indirectly) by the function.

We will obviously deal with the last one:

---

Lets' take a simple code and look at the assembly (`-O3`)

```
auto foo(int& a)
{
  a = 24;

  return a;
}
```

```
foo(int&):                               # @foo(int&)
        mov     dword ptr [rdi], 24
        mov     eax, 24
        ret
```

As you can see `mov eax, 24`. The returned value is set to `24`. This means that the compiler can assume that no other code can modify the object referenced by `a` (even when `a` is a non-const reference).

let's add a function call code before the return:

```
auto bar() -> void;

auto foo(int& a)
{
  a = 24;
  bar();
  return a;
}
```

```
foo(int&):                               # @foo(int&)
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, rdi
        mov     dword ptr [rbx], 24
        call    bar()
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbx]
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

The compiler doesn't have access to the body of `bar` and so it has to take into account that `bar` could modify the object referenced by `a`.

Now adding `const&` into the equation as per your question doesn't change the equation. The object could be modified **only by code called within the current function**.

Having `const&&` doesn't change this in any way. The object referenced by `a` can still be modified.

> As I understand rvalue reference means that given object is temporary,
>   so nobody else have access to its data

Not true. An rvalue reference can be bound to `prvalues` (temporaries) or `xvalues`. Your own example shows this:

```
operator const T && () { return std::move(val); }
```

here you bound to `val` which is not a temporary (if the enclosing object is not).

Jonathan Wakely nailed it in a commentary:

> Your example proves that const T&& doesn't have to be bound to a
>   temporary, and there could be several rvalue references bound to the
>   same thing:
>
> ```
> Immutable<int> i{};
> const int&& r1 = i;
> const int&& r2 = i;
> ```
>
> So This is no different to the `const&` case

And here is my take on it:

```
int g = 24;

auto bar() -> void { g = 11; };

auto foo(const int&& a)
{
  bar();
  return a;
}

auto test()
{
  return foo(std::move(g));
}
```

```
test():                               # @test()
        mov     dword ptr [rip + g], 11
        mov     eax, 11
        ret
```

The above code is valid<sup>1)</sup> and it shows that the object referenced by the `const int&&` parameter `a` is modified during the call of `foo`.

<sub><sup>1)</sup> although I am not 100% sure, I am fairly certain</sub>

Comment: So, access to rvalue reference by other ref isn't UB by Standard? It is sad.